# Missing group audience field(og) from node add form by panel

Tags: panels, organic-groups, chaos-tool-suite

I have 2 content types, and they are Organization(group) and Contact(group content)
From Contact, I add the group audience field and bundle with Organization.

When I use the node/add/contact from default node add form, everything is great.

I am trying to create another node/add/contact form from other url (organization/add_contact).
However, my problem is after setup a page(page management) and add the context with node add form, I find out my new add node form is missing the group audience field.

Is anyone have same problem or some setting was missed.......

Comment: I have the same problem. Thus the content created on this page (panels page) will not be assigned to any group.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in "og/includes/og.field.inc". When the form is built twice "og_field_widget_form()" returns an empty array, thus the element has no options and seems to be missing.

Here is a link to the bug tracker: https://www.drupal.org/node/2481709

Issue is still open. For now I just commented the offending if-block out.